# How to diagnose slow Web API request

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

We have a production web app running on a VM in Azure where we're seeing relatively simple ASP.NET Web API requests take 2-5 seconds when they should be serviced within roughly 50 ms.  I can routinely (8 times out of 10) repro against the site by requesting a detail page.  The detail page which makes 48 requests with 12 of them being Web API calls.  The requests for static content is serviced consistently in under 100 ms, often below 50 ms. We've gone through a number of diagnostics steps without success.

## Diagnostic Steps Taken

**Monitored performance counters**.  We set up a data collector set to check for: high CPU utilization, high network I/O, high disk activity, high memory utilization, high garbage collection rate/time, high tread/lock contention rate, high rate of exceptions, high pipeline instance count.  Nothing stood out.  In fact, CPU averages below 5 percent and doesn't exceed 10 percent during the problematic calls.

**Enabled interception on the API calls**.  Our Web API's are very thin wrappers around API calls.  We enabled Unity interception on the API calls so we could get some insight on the time it takes the API to service the request.  This indicates the calls are being serviced in under 15 ms.

**Enabled slow command interceptor**.  We enabled a custom Entity Framework Slow Command interceptor to watch for SQL that takes longer than 1 second to execute.  This occasionally flags a slow command, but it does not correlate with the slow Web API requests.  Oddly, the slow commands are simple commands with execution times in SSMS of 20 ms.

**Checked the Azure SQL Database**.  Since the slow command interceptor revealed slow commands, we checked the Azure SQL database to ensure there were no queries flagged as performing poorly and that we were not hitting our DTU threshold.  No queries were shown to be taking seconds to execute.  In fact, even queries that were flagged are executing in less than 200 ms.  Database is no where near the DTU threshold or quota.  We threw one of the slow commands into SSMS and examined the cost and execution time.  Cost was 0.006 and average execution time was 20 ms.

**Enabled IIS Failed Request Tracing**.  We enabled IIS failed request tracing and set a time threshold of 2 seconds.  Tracing catches the slow requests, but the trace logs don't reveal any part of the request that takes a long time.  In each case, there were only one or two events with a time higher than 0 ms.  The two events with time at all had times of roughly 30 ms and 350 ms.

**Disabled Compression**.  We had static content compression on.  We disabled it just to rule it out.  No effect.

**Removed a 3rd Party AV/Firewall**. We had a 3rd party AV/Firewall installed.  Since we were seeing indications that there might be some communication issues (slow queries and requests), we temporarily removed it to rule out any interference.

**Checked Azure Host**.  We looked at the Azure host performance counters for high resource utilization.  Everything was low.

### Server/App Info

Server is DS2v2 with 2 cores and 7 GB RAM.  It is running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.  CPU is E5-2673v3.
Web app is running .NET 4.6.2.  We don't make heavy use of ASP.NET outside of the Web APIs.  We don't rely on session state.  Pages, which are plain old HTML5, are truly stateless.

We are not seeing this problem on other web servers running the same version of this app.  We see the same slow behavior making requests from a browser instance running inside the machine as those coming from outside.

## Summary

It appears there is something between IIS and our API that's slowing the processing, but the diagnostic steps taken so far do not reveal anything.  Any  suggestions on how to locate the issue?

Comment: is the response slow even when the api is run locally on your development machine?

Comment: They're not.  Nor is it slow on other production servers.  That's the puzzling thing.  This code has been in place and performing well for years.

Comment: is it too late to just create a new VM and redeploy? Just to see if the behaviour replicates? It could just be a bad VM although I have never seen that happen on Azure.

Comment: We've redeployed the VM to move hosts.  We've also provisioned a new VM for testing.  Saw some issues in the test environment initially, but now it is performing fine.  Prod is still acting up.  Deploying a new VM for prod may be the best method to resolve, but I'd sure like to know what's going on.

Comment: I am not that technical to do deep analysis (hopefully someone else will), but I am glad that the issue has been isolated.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering an accurate answer, I have to know how are you retrieving your data?
For example, in some cases we would only need our user's ID in order to move further with the application.
So make sure you call only the columns which are crucial for the specific operation.
A simple scenario where need to display user's username in the application, you should go for:
`SELECT u.Username FROM AspNetUsers u Where u.Id = @ID`

Instead of:

`SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers WHERE Id = @ID`

I hope my answer helps. Best of Luck

Comment: We're using EF to get data.  We typically request just the data we need with projections.  We will include related entities if we know we will need the data.  However, in the many of the slow requests, we're just getting a single entity.  They're just not complex queries.